# How to get the JSON Body for CreateAsync Force.com Toolkit for .NET

Tags: c#, json, salesforce, force.com

Hi I am trying to create an Orderitem for an Order just created but I am getting this following error

*JSON Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row*

How do I get the JSON RAW Body that is being posted so I can understand better what is going on?

My Code

```
var record = await client.CreateAsync("OrderItem", orderItems);
```

Comment: You can run something like Fiddler to see the request and response or  you can add network tracing to  your config file but that is harder to read because it is not formatted for humans.

Comment: Can't capture the calls using fiddler from the toolkit at all.  In Fiddler Options, I already set https and ignore certificate errors and so on... any idea?

Comment: I guess try turning on network tracing in config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing